# Как можно сгенерировать ключ ssh-ed25519 на языке PHP?

Tags: php

Как можно сгенерировать ключ ssh-ed25519 на языке PHP?

Comment: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/phpCkSshKeyRef.html#method7

Answer (score 2):

Решено.

Решение использует библиотеку phpseclib3:

```
use phpseclib3\Crypt\EC;

$key = EC::createKey('Ed25519');

$public = $key->getPublicKey()->toString("openssh");
$private = $key->toString("openssh");
```